# Multidim Array, checking nonexistent neighbors

Tags: arrays, list, multidimensional-array, lua

got a list like this:

```
people[i][j]
```

where **i** and **j** are both scaled from 0 to **n**.

Every entry looks like:

```
people[1][1] = {genome = 0x000000, immune = 0, healing = 0}
```

Now I'm iterating through the people and checking each neighbor like:

```
if people[i][j+1] then ....
if people[i][j-1] then ....
if people[i+1][j] then ....
if people[i-1][j] then ....
```

But those people standing on the border of the array, doesn't have neighbors in one or two directions and this is my issue.

> attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

I know **why** this error is coming, but I have now idea how to fix this proplem in my scenario.

(btw: I'm trying to solve this puzzle, maybe this info helps you to understand my scenario 
Due I have to check the neighbors.
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/be-an-epidemiologist)

there are **n** *4 - 4 entries wich only have 3 and 4 entries wich only have 2 neighbors. I could store them in an additional list in which I could use an other checkingprocedure, but this would be a pretty poor solution i guess.
Also, due performance is a big issue here. (assumed that **n** is 1000, the 4 checks have to be done 1000² times per draw, several draws again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, here are two:

```
if people[i+1] and people[i+1][j] then
```

or

```
if (people[i+1] or {})[j] then
```

You could also explicitly test if you are on the border but this is error prone:

```
if j < n and people[i][j+1] then ....
if j > 0 and people[i][j-1] then ....
if i < n and people[i+1][j] then ....
if i > 0 and people[i-1][j] then ....
```

Note that the code you showed actually only has a problem with the first dimension (`i` index) so only doing this also works:

```
if people[i][j+1] then ....
if people[i][j-1] then ....
if i < n and people[i+1][j] then ....
if i > 0 and people[i-1][j] then ....
```

Yet another solution would be to add two empty arrays to `people` before running your loop:

```
people[-1] = {}
people[n+1] = {}
```

Comment: I do not understand this syntax : --  {})[j]   -- How does it work?

Comment: `people[i+1] or {}` returns an empty table if `people[i+1]` is `nil`, so it is valid to index it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator.

If the indexing is from **`0`** to **`n - 1`**, you can use: `(x + 1) % n` and `(x - 1 + n) % n` for finding next and previous neighbours respectively. If, instead, the indexing is from **`1`** instead of **`0`** (to **`n`**), add *one* (**`1`**) to both the values above.

```
if people[i][(j + 1) % n] then ....
if people[i][(j - 1 + n) % n] then ....
if people[(i + 1) % n][j] then ....
if people[(i - 1 + n) % n][j] then ....
```

---

Please note that the limits play a major role here.

Comment: This solution transforms the grid into a torus, meaning that e.g. `people[0][3]` and `people[n][3]` are now neighbors. If this is what you want, use this! Otherwise, see my answer.